# Alterar uma pergunta já respondida para outra parecida que exija outra resposta pode ser considerada camaleão?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

No dia 8/10, foi criado a pergunta:

[Como trocar informações entre Activitys?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35336/como-trocar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-entre-activitys/)

A pergunta recebeu três respostas, incluindo uma aceita para o problema.

No dia 13/10, as respostas aparentemente não eram mais capazes de ajudar seu problema, então o O.P criou [uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36736/como-trocar-o-valor-de-variaveis-entre-classes), que por ele não explicar o porquê das soluções não sancionarem seu problema, foi fechada como duplicata!

Então o O.P. alterou a sua pergunta anterior, invalidando as respostas, pois mesmo o problema parecendo semelhante *(ao menos aos meus olhos, já que não costumo desenvolver para androids)*, as respostas já são incapazes de solucioná-las.

Eu cheguei a perguntar nos comentários da pergunta se a solução anterior não funcionava, mas depois comecei a pensar que poderia ser uma pergunta camaleão.

O certo da pergunta seria fazer uma nova, indicando que a solução que recebeu anteriormente não funcionava, ou está realmente certo essa alteração, mesmo com 5 dias que já estava respondida?

Comment: +1 muito boa a pergunta. Ainda por cima antes tinha sido fechada como duplicata outra pergunta.

Comment: [Aqui a duplicata](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36736/como-trocar-o-valor-de-variaveis-entre-classes)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Será que esta é uma "pergunta camaleão"?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/ser%c3%a1-que-esta-%c3%a9-uma-pergunta-camale%c3%a3o)

Comment: Não acho duplicata, melhor debater cada pergunta separadamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu pus ali a duplicata da pergunta a que se refere o Gammeth... E não esta como duplicata.

Comment: @JorgeB. O brasofilo e mais alguém consideraram *esta* como duplicata de http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/ser%c3%a1-que-esta-%c3%a9-uma-pergunta-camale%c3%a3o?lq=1

Comment: @brasofilo esta é um caso especifico como podes ver na explicação/resposta do bfavaretto.

Comment: É fato, se é [meta-tag:pergunta-específica], quase que por definição, não pode ser duplicatada... @bfavaretto, c/c JorgeB

Comment: Vou acrescentar os detalhes da pergunta duplicata nesta pergunta, pela comodidade daqueles que ainda lerão esse caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta foi editada depois que [a pergunta seguinte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36736/como-trocar-o-valor-de-variaveis-entre-classes) do autor foi fechada como duplicata dela. E entendo que tenha sido fechada porque as soluções para se acessar determinada propriedade a partir de várias classes são as mesmas, ou muito próximas, independentemente de a propriedade ser um `TextView` ou um `float` (avisem se eu estiver dizendo bobagem, Java não é a minha especialidade).

Portanto fecharam a segunda pergunta considerando que a resposta já estava na primeira. Isso levou o autor a editar a primeira e remover a aceitação da sua resposta. De fato foi uma mudança-camaleão – e eu mesmo editei a pergunta depois disso e não percebi, peço desculpas.

Me parece que a melhor solução seria reverter as edições e reabrir a segunda pergunta. Acontece que ela é tão parecida com a primeira que seria ideal o autor explicar melhor o problema antes de reabrirmos, pois não está claro o que está causando o problema. Entendo que as soluções da pergunta aberta se aplicam também à pergunta fechada (exceto pela troca de `getString` para `getFloat` em uma das respostas).

Comment: É isso mesmo @bfavaretto

Comment: Sinceramente concordo com isso, mas entendo que a pergunta foi fechada porque o autor praticamente repetiu a pergunta... Pelo menos ao meu entender, ele poderia ter feito o que fez, se explicasse o porquê do `static` não ter funcionado, ou que problemas existem nas soluções que recebeu... Não posso dizer com certeza por causa da minha inexperiência, tanto com java, quanto com o próprio SO, mas até onde entendi, poderia ser válido...

Comment: @Gammeth é mesmo assim como dizes. Era dizer o porque de o static ou outro método na pergunta original, o porque de não funcionar. Como estava era mesmo duplicata. Eu cheguei a responder e tudo, mas apaguei porque era mesmo duplicata sem tirar nem por.

Comment: No caso, para reabrir a segunda pergunta, seria necessário no mínimo que o O.P. explicasse o porquê da solução não servir... Acho que, nesse caso, seria melhor orientarmos ao O.P. que além de explicar, coloque também exemplos dos casos que não funcionam, afinal, ele mesmo indica que seu problema é uma "suposição"...

Comment: Deixei um comentário para ele na segunda pergunta, @Gammeth: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36736/como-trocar-o-valor-de-variaveis-entre-classes?lq=1#comment70825_36736

Comment: @Gammeth Reverti as edições, e pedi para o autor editar a outra pergunta (no momento ainda fechada). http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35336/como-trocar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-entre-classes#comment70974_35336

Comment: @JorgeB. Inacreditável: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35336/como-trocar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-entre-classes?noredirect=1#comment71007_35336

Comment: @bfavaretto nunca vi coisa igual ahahahah.

Comment: aê, favaretto, não sabia que você *faz coisas* pro pessoal aí sob demanda, legal! Anotado aqui, quando precisar dou um toque :o)